# How to convert a date/time column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame in R with a column that contains date/time as 
`2018-06-01T19:55:57.000Z`. This time is in GMT. It is of type character. How can I convert this field to a central time zone time, showing the date, time and timezone in the column and also cut out the `000Z` that are there in the end?

I ran the code `as.POSIXct(data$datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` but it returns `NA` in all the fields. Any ideas?

```
[1] "2018-06-01T19:30:02.000Z" ""                         "2018-04-23T20:51:13.000Z" "2018-05-25T18:06:53.000Z"
 [5] "2018-05-31T21:59:19.000Z" "2018-06-01T16:30:36.000Z" "2018-06-01T14:16:04.000Z" "2018-05-18T22:03:41.000Z"
 [9] "2018-05-15T17:15:22.000Z" "2018-06-01T18:57:33.000Z" "2018-06-01T17:48:04.000Z" ""                        
[13] "2018-06-01T16:10:10.000Z" "2018-05-31T19:34:01.000Z" "2018-05-18T13:34:32.000Z" "2018-06-01T19:55:57.000Z"
```

Comment: Please provide example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lubridate` methods

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2018-06-01T19:55:57.000Z"
```

Comment: @akrun-: how do I add timezone and cut out the 000Z?

Comment: @alli  You can specify the `tz = 'GMT'` or whatever you wanted in `ymd_hms`.  It will automatically cut out of the 000Z

Comment: how do I cut out the 000z?

Comment: @Alli Please apply the `ymd_hms` it will strip off that part

Comment: it worked. How do I convert the UTC time to  central time?